# How to ReLoadData UICollectionView using RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I'm practicing RxSwift and doing some task with searchBar and CollectionView.
when i run the app, collectionview show giphy files.
but when i input some text in searchBar, collectionView doesn't reload any data.
so there's empty cell when searchBar has text.

I don't know what should I do.. please help me!

here's the problem's code.

```
let _ = gifSearchBar.rx.text.orEmpty
            .throttle(.milliseconds(500), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .flatMapLatest { (query) -> Observable<[GIFViewModel]> in
                
                guard let model = self.gifDataViewModel else { return .just([]) }
                if query.isEmpty {
                    return model.fetchGifViewModels().catchErrorJustReturn([])
                }
                
                return model.searchGifViewModels(keyword: query)
            }.bind(to: gifCollectionView.rx.items(
                    cellIdentifier: SearchCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier,
                    cellType: SearchCollectionViewCell.self)) { row, gif, cell in
                cell.configure(gif: gif)
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and the screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyULw.jpg)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code, and your description implies that it is working, but the server isn't finding any gifs for the search terms you are using.

Comment: which server you mean??

Comment: The source of the gifs.

Comment: you means that i have to add some code before `bind(to...` that find search term gif??

Comment: i've been research codes like this.. but there's only tableView, and not more source about reloadData collectionView. can you please give me sample code or reference about this?

Comment: No, I mean `searchGifViewModels(keyword: query)` is only returning gifs that match the query (which apparently is none of them.) Either that, or the function isn't working.